# increasing the size of spot indicator on JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTextArea in my java code, I want to increase the size of the cursor which points the writing position/spot on the JTextArea, I am not talking about the cursor which points the position of mouse, but the cursor/pointer which indicates the spot of writing on JTextArea. Please tell how I can increase its size?

Answer (score 3):

The text cursor is called `Caret`. You can change the caret by setting a new caret with the `JTextComponent.setCaret()` method (`JTextArea` extends `JTextComponent`).

Carets are responsible rendering themselves, so you can paint as big caret as you would like to. Basically what you should do is extend `DefaultCaret` and override its `paint()` method.

Here's an example of a custom caret:

http://java-sl.com/tip_overwrite_mode.html

Answer (score 0):

one way is to simply increase the font size. Is this what you want? or do you want to keep the font small?

```
Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 30);
txt.setFont(font);
```